# Event emitting from the Interface

Tags: solidity, remix

When I am calling this code(it's a test code related to the bigger contract, but the same problem can be observed here) I am receiving an error - ParserError - expected ';' but got '.' .

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.12;

import "./TRC20.sol";

contract Contract1 is ITRC20{
    
    address token;
    
    function emitter() {
        
        emit  ITRC20(token).Transfer(msg.sender, msg.sender, 25);
    }
    
}
```

why can't I emit an event this way?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Events are different from functions, you can only emit events of your own contract, there's no way to emit events of another contract.

`ITRC20(token)` is basically another contract at the `token` address, you can access its public functions with something like `ITRC20(token).transfer(msg.sender, 25)`, but you cannot access the `Transfer` event of that contract with the dot operator, thus the compiler does not expect to see that dot operator in the `emit` statement.